# Same value in independent variables for one section of the respondents

Tags: similarities

I am planning to use 6 indexes (community index) as independent variables for 12 communities.
And planning to run regression where the dependent variable will be collected from the individual responses of households of these communities.
While doing so, for one community, the independent variables will show same value against the individuals of it. Thus, will it be possible to run regression?
I am putting an example of it.

```
Yi =20 30 40 11 20 50 10 10 44 55 35 45 66 77 88 17
X1i = 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 
X2i= 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 
X3i= 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 
X4i= 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3
X5i= 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 
X6i= 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is just an example only.
I am just willing to know that whether it's possible to run regression or not!
And if yes, then will it be a linear regression or some other form of regression should be used?

Comment: same value against the individuals of it.? please elaborate.

Comment: Yes repeated values in the design matrix are no problem, though you will need to account for the correlation within communities via a mixed model. If that sounds too complicated, an initial analysis with plain 'ol linear regression is fine, but be wary of its p-values/confidence interval.

Comment: @Subhash_C._Davar

Comment: @Subhash_C._Davar
Suppose I am interested in knowing about the role of different dimension of institution on people's income. And I have taken 12 villages. Households' income from these villages will be captured. And suppose we have 400 sample household. Now the dimensions of institution of each village will be measured using an index. Suppose the institution has three dimensions, 'variety', 'trust' and 'room for autonomous change'. For each village, each of the dimensions will have a particular value. Thus, each dimension will have 12 values as there are 12 villages. In a regression, where I